# Android: Need to reference view when using findViewById?

Tags: java, android, xml, view, reference

This comes more out of curiosity. I have had this snippet:

```
View mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.myButton, null);
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.mButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
       ...
```

And first I tried it **without** the `mView`-reference and it works as expected. So it is also described in the `Buttons`-section of *developer.android.com*

However, **with** `mView` also works.

My question is, is it really needed to reference it? And what could be the purpose behind it?

Why it works both ways? Could there be any drawbacks of any of the given usages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why it works both ways?

if it works both ways it could mean two different things. First you passed `myButton.xml` to `setContentView` as well. In this case the Activity has, as part of its view hierarchy, a view  with id `mButton`. It works as expected, but of course, the `OnClickListener`, in the case of the inflated layout is purpose less, unless you add the inflated view to the `Activity`'s view hierarchy. If you didn't pass `myButton.xml` to `setContentView`, it means that you have two separate layouts that contain the same `ImageButton` with the same id. Also in this case are valid the considerations about `OnClickListener`.

Comment: I truly have two different layouts, but how is the id contained in both?

Comment: the id is unique. It is generated the first time you declare @+id/ in one of your layout at compile time. You can reuse the way you prefer

Answer (score 1):

You are in two case:

## Case 1

```
(Button) findViewById(R.id.mButton);
```

You are in an activity, where [`Activity.findViewById()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) will browse the actual activity view tree.
This activity will have a view from the moment you use [`setContentView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)), [`addContentView(..)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#addContentView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)) or other inflater method

## Case 2

```
(Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.mButton);
```

You are searching for a view **in** another view, using the [`View.findViewById()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)). This method is used for getting a view from a Fragment for example.

Comment: Yes, I use another view with `addContentView()`.